# Java - Server port number retry

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop

I want to make a condition that when the user enters a number less than 1024 for the port number it'll ask them to try again. I know how to do a if statement and a simple while loop but not too sure how to do this.

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;

class Server {
    public void start (int num) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(num);
        if(num  < 1024){
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(num);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is wrong. I know maybe a while loop is the one to use but I tried similar approach but still error. If the user enters a number less than 1024 then it'll ask them to type in the numbers again. Keep doing it until number is >=1024.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: make sure that you decouple the user interface from the design of the main functionality. This is a very important design principle which should hold for any application but the most basic tools (or quick mashups before you start creating the actual application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw `IllegalArgumentException` when `num < 1024`. The caller of this method should use try .. catch block (maybe inside a loop to retry)

The caller can use:

```
Server s = new Server;
int maxRetries = 10;
int retry = 0;
while(retry < maxRetries){
    try {
        retry++;
        // Read value to num somehow (scanner maybe)
        s.start(num);
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        // print error string
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the keeprun used? I did ' if(num < 1024){start(num);} ' then ' catch (Exception e) ' but that brings me back to square one because after the error message pops up, it doesn't tell me to retry entering num again.

Comment: Added an option based on max retries allowed.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int port = scanner.nextInt();
    while (port < 1024) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid port");
        port = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Port is "+port);
    //Put the logic here to start the server socket.
}
```

Try this, replace the scanner part with your value.

Answer (score 1):

You just need scanner class. See http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/user_input.html

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
int portEntered=user_input.nextInt();
while(user_input<1024)
{
//  message stating user has entered number less than 1024 using sysout
portEntered= user_input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with testing just that case. Just try to create the ServerSocket, and if it throws BindException for *any* reason re-prompt the user and retry.

Comment: Wouldn't putting up a check for port number less than 1024 isn't a good idea? That port range (<1024) is not supposed to be programmer defined.
It is reserved by IANA.